# How SCDF stream diagram reflect multiple source channel?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

If a have a source app(named A-Source)  which has multiple channels to emit messages, eg. 
channelA.destination=b-topic, channelB.destination=c-topic. 
The receiver for b-topic is B-Sink,   for c-topic is C-Sink. 
How can i construct my stream,  describe them like:   A|B  and A|C? And if so, i think just part of my A-Source code is useful in every stream.

So my question is: how SCDF stream DSL deal with multiple tap for single source app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use named channel destinations in the Stream DSL.

For example:

`dataflow:>stream create tap1 --definition ":b-topic > B-SInk"
dataflow:>stream create tap2 --definition ":c-topic > C-SInk"`

Comment: And how about the DSL for A-Source ?
`A-Source  > :b-topic`
`A-Source > :c-topic` 
if so, then just part of my A-Source  code is useful in the above two stream.

Comment: Yes, the named destinations can be either source channel or sink channel destinations.

Comment: So it mean the scdf just cannot orchestrate stream like  A->B and A->C

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by that. Can you specify the stream definition and specify which do you think SCDF cannot orchestrate?

Comment: eg. A-Source app have three channels to B-Sink. How to write the Stream DSL for it.